# URL link preview issue in react JS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

We are having one problem while generating a link preview for our react application URL's. Actually we have the requirement to display the dynamic link preview for different URLs.

We are able to add the link preview by using open graph tags in our index.html file placed under the public folder.

But once we tried to add dynamic metadata using the "react-meta" or "helmet" package. it is successfully changing the title of the application. but links preview are not working after making these changes.
so I kindly let me know if there is any way that we can different link preview for different urls for react application. Thanks in advance.

Comment: by dynamic, do you mean your og meta tags changes at runtime?

Comment: sounds like `helmet` (`react-meta`) conflicts with your way of handling link preview when it comes to accessing/manipulating your meta tags. I think we'd need more details on how exactly you're managing your link preview (og tags), which would presumably reveal the nature of that conflict